# Why is plotly graph's Scattergl not working for scatter plots

Tags: python, plotly

Trying to use Scatter Gl because it is apparently handles more data than Scatter svg. However I cant work out what is wrong.  `mode='markers'` should produce a point, but it does not seem to work for me.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
traces = []
 
traces.append( go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[10,20,5], mode = 'markers', name='scatter point') )
traces.append( go.Scattergl(x=[1,2,3], y=[11,22,11], mode = 'lines', name='scattergl lines') )
traces.append( go.Scattergl(x=[1,2,3], y=[22,33,10], mode = 'markers', name='scattergl point') )
traces.append( go.Scattergl(x=[1,2,3], y=[22,33,5], mode = 'markers+lines', name='scattergl lines + point') )

fig = go.Figure(data=traces)
fig.show()
```

Am I doing something wrong here ?

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here... (3,10) is a marker as you defined it. (0,22) and (1,33) are mixed with scattergl lines+points.

Comment: Ive raised a question on the github project thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to note here:

(1) the green dots are obscured by the purple line as the first two coordinates are identical — if you click on the `scattergl lines + point` in the legend to unselect these points, you will see the green dots

[image]

(2) you should be able to see the remaining green dot

[image]

(3) if you want to see both green and purple dots even when they overlap, you can modify the opacity and marker size. if you want to see the hover information of both sets of data at the same time, you can select the `Compare data on hover` button in the upper corner of the plot menu.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
traces = []
 
traces.append( go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3], y=[10,20,5], mode = 'markers', name='scatter point'))
traces.append( go.Scattergl(x=[1,2,3], y=[11,22,11], mode = 'lines', name='scattergl lines') )
traces.append( go.Scattergl(x=[1,2,3], y=[22,33,10], mode = 'markers', name='scattergl point', marker=dict(size=10), opacity=0.6))
traces.append( go.Scattergl(x=[1,2,3], y=[22,33,5], mode = 'markers+lines', name='scattergl lines + point'))

fig = go.Figure(data=traces)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What you are saying is not true.  If you look closely at my example, all the purple dots are missing and the you can see where we are both hovering on point (3,10), my graph is missing the dot that you have.  So our setups must differ.

Comment: What version of Plotly are you using?

Comment: Its plotly==4.9.0 with python3.6.  Ive been playing with this for a bit on 2 computers. This works on a computer with Fedora 31 (downgraded to python3.6 env). My work which has CentOS 7 is failing to draw these with the same virtual env.

Comment: This may be a bug in plotly because the CentOS 7 box can produce the dots properly in a jpeg if you do `fig.write_image("test.jpeg")`. Ill open this as a bug see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like a bug. If you get a response from the Plotly team on this issue, please post it as an answer. I think everyone will benefit from knowing why this is happening!